# Is it possible to do return in App:before filter in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Before app starts I need to check a few things and if the go wrong load error page. All is done in `App:before` filter except the `return` as it just doesn’t work. Is somehow possible to stop the app from `before` filter?

Answer (score 2):

I would try by throwing an exception. You could define something like a `BootstrapException`. Then you throw it if something goes wrong in `App::before()`:

```
App::before(function ($request) {
    // do checks

    if (/* checks failed */) {
       throw new BootstrapException;
    }
});
```

After that, you can listen to that exception (e.g.) in `start/global.php` where there is already an `App::error()` call:

```
App::error(function (BootstrapException $exception, $code) {
    return Response::view('errorpage', [], $code);
});
```

I'm not sure about this, but put your `App::error()` before the *catch all* `App::error(function (Exception $exception, $code) { ... });` that is defined in `start/global.php`, because every exception is derived from `Exception` so your `BootstrapException` would be caught by that error handling call and not by your specific error handling code.